# How to fill a random object with random data at runtime

Tags: c#, testing

I want to create a little testing tool for my program, which fills all properties of a random object (unknown type at compile time). A sample structure:

```
    public class HeadObject
    {
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public CompanyAddress CompanyAddress { get; set; }
        public List<Details> Details{ get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }
```

and e.g the class Company would look like this:

```
    public class Company
   {
        public string CompanyName{ get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
        public Address Adress{ get; set; }
        public int CompanyNo{ get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
   }
```

its pretty simplified because in each HeadOjbect there are around 30 properties which may contain sub properties or a property can be a list etc.. I need to populate ~30 HeadObjects at runtime. I already tried it with different libraries like [GenFu](https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu), [nBuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder) or [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus).

The last 2 have the problem that I have to fill the properties by myself only the data is generated. GenFu looks like it can only deal with primitive properties like int, string, ... And if you imagine the HeadObject as a root of a tree, then there would be

~ 300 Nodes per tree

Height of a tree: between 1 and 7(!)

~30 Different trees (HeadObjects)

so it would take days to write this all down by myself and maintenance would be a pain.

I appreciate any kind of idea.

#### **UPDATE**

Thanks for your replies! How can I initialize the objects? e.g I get the Company property of my head object and then I want to initialize it to be able to fill it. My method (its recursive) starts like this:

```
    private static T FillAllProperties<T>(T masterObject) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            
            Type masterType = masterObject.GetType();

            T headObject = new T();

            ......IF primitive Type fill it and return the value
            otherwise get Properties into firstProperties.......
            
       foreach (var propertyInfo in firstProperties)
       {
           var objectInstance = FillAllProperties(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
  
headObject.GetType().GetProperty($"{propertyInfo.Name}").SetValue(headObject, objectInstance, null);
           }
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. is my way to initialize the generic type correct?
2. at the recursive call I get the following error :" The type 'System.Type' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T'....

I probably need another "construction" for this algorithm, but how..?

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? How to use reflection to fill a property? How to generate a random string for something like `CompanyName`? What have you tried other than reviewing some libraries which dont do what you want?

Comment: Do you have demands on the generated data? If not, you can iterate recursively through all the properties via reflection until simple types (`int`, `string`, etc.) are reached. Then use `Random` to fill them up.

Comment: "How to use reflection to fill a property" I didint know about that possibility in C#. So I could gather all properties of an object and iterate until I reach the simple types. so would be PropertyInfo.SetValue() the right choice? Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 2):

You are going to go through deep pain...

Basically the idea is to iterate through the object's properties and randomly fill them.

You can iterate using [YourObject.GetType().GetProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8) then using [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=netframework-4.8) to know the type.

Then with each Proprety Type you can check whether it is a simple (i.e. int, double...) structure or a more complex object (by using [Type.IsPrimitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netframework-4.8), [Type.IsClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isclass?view=netframework-4.8) or [Type.IsValueType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?view=netframework-4.8)).

- If it a class, you recursively call the same method, because it means you have a complex type.
- If it is a structure, then maybe you should iterate over the fields instead of the properies ?
- If it is a primitive you can set its value using [PropertyInfo.SetValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8), but how are you going to randomize anything ? You need to perform a switch on .Net base types then generate a value at random for each type.

By the way, a string is a class, not a primitive, so you will need to make a special case for this one.

Also, `List<string>` is a funny one, because it is an Enumerable object. So it is another specific case.

And if you want to have fun, try out a Dictionary, or better, Tuple...

Anyway, there is no simple way to perform this. Your simple testing tool will soon become a nightmare because of all the cases you couldn't even see from far away...

Maybe there is a better option to test your program than filling it with random values that don't have any actual meaning ?

Comment: Thank you! im currently struggeling with the initialization of my generic type.. Because i need to initialize any property before im able to assign it right? But how ? I've postet my current state as an update above

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the properties at runtime, you will have to use Reflection. But starting with 30 properties, I would probably use it regardless (or look if I made any mistakes in my design). Writing that much manually is just too prone to mistakes.

A alternative might be to have a `ISelfRandomizing` interface with a `SelfRandomize()` function, so each type input can carry it's own randomization code. And hope people actually provide it.

Something that might be viable for your case: structs by default use reflection for comparison. What would be the equivalent of a base class for them, has reflection based fallback code. You are invited to override it, but if you do not it just "works". You could make a abstract base class that you use for all those classes. That way you only need to write the reflection code once.

As for the actual randomization: [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random). A common mistake is creating new instances of Random in a loop. Do not do that. You want to keep a single Random instance around as long as possible, for optimal randomisation. I have no sensible way to transform a Integer return into a string, so the next best non-sensible thing is to create a large random number and call `ToString()` on it. That will give you *something* to put in those spots at least.